# Adding bootstrap best practice

Tags: php, bootstrapping

Is it a good idea just to

Include 'bootstrapcdn.php';

Content of the file will be cdn bootstrap links.
It will shorten my header file across my entire web.

Thank you

Comment: I think the include will not slow down your page. 
But if you serve the files from your local server, this will speed up the loading

Comment: You mean to do like a file_get_contents of the CDN links and serve via your webpage?

The reason that's not done, is because you then have to first download the files on to your server (every page load) and then serve it to the user.

Having the CDN links in the HTML as <link>'s allows the user to get the files directly from the source (faster and better, read up what a CDN is used for).

Comment: Nope. Store the files on his own server, then call the bootdtrap with this included file.